# Estimate integral $\int\limits_0^{\infty}\operatorname{sech}\left(\varepsilon x\right)\cos\left(kx\right)\,dx,\,$ with $\,k,\varepsilon>0$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, asymptotics

$
\newcommand{\sech}{\operatorname{sech}}
$
Is there any analytic/asymptotic way to estimate  the value of the  integral:

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} \sech\left(\varepsilon x\right)\cdot \cos\left(kx\right)\,dx , \qquad k,\varepsilon > 0,
$$
where $\varepsilon $ is a small parameter.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think you need an asymptotic estimate of this integral.  It is essentially a Fourier transform of the Sech function, which is another Sech function.

Comment: thank you , so the integral above is 0?

Comment: Yes ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: According to a CAS, the result seems to be $$\frac{\pi }{2 \epsilon } \text{sech}\left(\frac{\pi  k}{2 \epsilon }\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\newcommand{\sech}{\operatorname{sech}} \begin{align*}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(nx)}{\cosh x}\,dx &= 2\sum_{m\geq 0}(-1)^m \int_{0}^{+\infty}\cos(n x)e^{-(2m+1)x}\,dx\\&=2\sum_{m\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^m (2m+1)}{n^2+(2m+1)^2}\\&=\frac{\pi}{2}\,\sech\frac{\pi n}{2}\end{align*}$$
since:
$$ \text{Res}\left(\sec\frac{\pi z}{2},z=2m+1\right)=\frac{2}{\pi}(-1)^{m+1} $$
hence it follows that:
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\sech(\varepsilon x)\cos(kx)\,dx = \frac{\pi}{2\varepsilon}\,\sech\left(\frac{\pi k}{2\varepsilon}\right)$$
as checked by Claude Leibovici with a CAS. It is well-known that the hyperbolic secant is more or less a fixed point of the Fourier transform.

Comment: I am trying to write a derivation for the above identity using the logarithmic derivative of Euler's infinite product formulas for the sine and cosine functions, but am unable to find a way to do so. It seems to depend on $\displaystyle\sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty\frac{(-1)^m}{m^2+a^2}=\frac\pi a~\text{csch }a\pi$.

Comment: It is obviously related to $\displaystyle\sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty\frac1{m^2+a^2}=\frac\pi a~\coth a\pi$, but I'm not sure how exactly.

Comment: @Lucian: $$\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{(-1)^m}{m^2+a^2}+\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{1}{m^2+a^2}=2\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{1}{4m^2+a^2}=\frac{\pi}{a}\coth\frac{\pi a}{2},$$ hence: $$\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{(-1)^m}{m^2+a^2}=\frac{\pi}{a}\coth\frac{\pi a}{2}-\frac{\pi}{a}\coth\frac{\pi a}{1}.$$

Comment: I thought about something similar along those lines, but wasn't able to spot the exact details, for some reason. Thanks!

Comment: @Lucian: you're welcome, as always.